# How to display pages in my way Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I have a problem with my navigation. I want to display all of my pages and theirs child pages. I want to display the child in a dropdown menu I got. In the code you can see how it works if I hardcode the meny. Now I want it to work with wp_list_pages(); so I dont haft to hardcode in for every page.

I want to display my pages like this, in my wordpress site

```
<div id="navigationContainer">
<ul id="navigation">

<li class="navLi">
<a href="" title="" class="navA">Start</a>
</li>

<li class="navLi dropdown">
<a href="" title="" class="navA">Page</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="" title="">Child</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="navLi dropdown">
<a href="" title="" class="navA">Parent</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="" title="">Child</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Child</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Child</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Child</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="navLi">
<a href="" title="" class="navA">Page</a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for now.

// Erik

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `dropdown` class by adding the following code to your functions.php file:

```
function add_parent_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args )
{
    if ( ! empty( $args['has_children'] ) )
        $css_class[] = 'dropdown';
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'add_parent_class', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: I get this from your function:

`<li class="page_item page-item-249 navLi dropdown">

<a href="">Start</a>

<ul class="children" style="z-index: 101; display: none; ">
 
<li class="page_item page-item-251">
<a href="">CHild</a>
</li>
 
<li class="page_item page-item-254">
<a href="">CHilden</a>
</li>

</ul>
</li>`

But I want to remove from the childrens `<li class="page_item page-item-254">` I only want it to display `<li>`.

And the `<ul class="children" style="z-index: 101; display: none; ">` I want to remove 'class="children"'

thanks

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting those classes?

Read the following post for ways to remove them: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201101/cleaner_html_from_the_wordpress_wp_list_pages_function/